# JavaScript new Table row Class not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

In my web application, There is a table and *Add* button.

Whenever the user clicks on the **Add** button, from javascript, I load the new row to the table.

In the row, there is a  element and for that class, I added the **Select2** *js-dropdown* class when adding to the new row.

But when it was added, Js-dropdown class was not applied.

How can I add it?

this is the current code.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>MEASURE BY</th>
      <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
      <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
    <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the javascript code.

```
  $(function () {

    $("#add").click(function () {
      var newRow = $(
        '<tr id="tablerow' +
        counter +
        '"> ' +
        "<td>" +
        '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
        counter +
        "</strong></label>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="40%">' +
        '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select js-dropdown" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
        counter +
        ']" id="ItemId"' + counter + 'required="required" ' +
        "</select>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="10%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Qty[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="10%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="20%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Unit_Price[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="20%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Line_Total[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
        counter +
        ');">x</button>' +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>"
      );

      var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); // Find the <select> element in the new row

      // Populate the <select> element with options
      dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {

        var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);

        selectElement.append(optionElement);

      });

      newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
      counter++;
      return false;
    });

  });
```

Comment: _"But when it was added, Js-dropdown class was not applied."_ - I suppose what you actually mean is, that you only get a normal select field, and not the "fancy" Select2 thing? Well Select2 does not apply retroactively to elements added to the document later on, so you will need to initialize the Select2 on your _new_ select field now.

Comment: There is nothing for `$("#add").click(function () {` Perhaps you meant to include the actual code (including the link to the CDN for jQuery and select2 to your example code?  Suggest you create a snippet that actually runs here.

Comment: Your code as posted will produce invalid HTML when/if that button does exist and you click it twice.  Suggest you use a template instead of this "strung on string" you currently have in code.  Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select2 jquery plugin work on new select element added to DOM, you need to initialize it on this select.

```js
$(()=>{
  
  let $target = $("#target");
  let $btn = $("#add");
  
  $btn.on('click', function(){
    let $select = $("<select><option>first</option><option>second</option></select>");
    $target.append($select);
    $select.select2(); // this must be called after append
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

**edit**

You have a syntax error, so it may not work for you.
replace
`']" id="ItemId"' + counter + 'required="required" ' +`
On
`']" id="ItemId' + counter + '" required="required" ' +`
I fixed this error see below.

```js
$(function () {
  let counter = 1;
  let dropdownOptions = [{Value:'0', Text: 'first'}, {Value:'1', Text: 'second'}];
    $("#add").click(function () {
      var newRow = $(
        '<tr id="tablerow' +
        counter +
        '"> ' +
        "<td>" +
        '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
        counter +
        "</strong></label>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="40%">' +
        '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select js-dropdown" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
        counter +
        ']" id="ItemId' + counter + '" required="required" ' +
        "</select>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="10%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Qty[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="10%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="20%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Unit_Price[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
        "</td>" +
        '<td width="20%">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Line_Total[' +
        counter +
        ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
        counter +
        ');">x</button>' +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>"
      );

      var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); // Find the <select> element in the new row

      // Populate the <select> element with options
      dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {

        var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);

        selectElement.append(optionElement);
      });

      
      newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
      selectElement.select2();
      
      
      counter++;
      return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>MEASURE BY</th>
      <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
      <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
    <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add">click me</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delayed response.  I tried your answer to apply mine. But still didn't work it. So Past few days I keep trying but same results. I don't know that I'm doing this wrongly. Could you take my code as an example and try to add your code?

Comment: I edited my post, check again and correct syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

A little different approach; sorry this is just a really really fast post here:

- use an object to hold the constants and not global.
- No need for global counter; seems overly complex to even NEED that used (use classes?)
- use a template and cloned that to make markup simpler to edit/understand
- some simple wire-up of event handlers that do little here.

```js
$(function() {
  function handleTableRowRemoval(event) {
    const row = event.target.closest('tr.row-thing');
    const rowCount = row.dataset.Count;
    $(row).remove();
    //whatever else needs done: removeTr(rowCount);
  }

  function handlePriceBaseEvent(event) {
    //do whatever calQtyBase(this);
  }

  function handleSelectChangeEvent(event) {
    // whatever sendInfo(this);
  }
  $("#add").on('click', function(event) {
    const newThings = {
      templateselector: "#new-row",
      rowIdBase: "tablerow-",
      newRowId: "",
      tableSelector: '#submissionTable tbody',
      selectSelector: '.form-select.js-dropdown.item-id',
      count: 0,
      dropdownOptions: [{
        Value: '0',
        Text: 'first'
      }, {
        Value: '1',
        Text: 'second'
      }]
    };

    const table = document.querySelector(newThings.tableSelector);
    const template = document.querySelector(newThings.templateselector);
    const cloneRow = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    newThings.currentCount = $(table).data("currentcount") * 1;

    // id might not be needed?
    newThings.newRowId = newThings.rowIdBase + newThings.count;
    cloneRow.id = newThings.newRowId;
    // what we work with 
    const selectControl = cloneRow.querySelector(newThings.selectSelector);
    const qtyBase = cloneRow.querySelector('.form-control.qty-base');
    const unitPrice = cloneRow.querySelector('.form-control.unit-price');
    const measureBy = cloneRow.querySelector('.form-control.measure-by');
    const lineTotal = cloneRow.querySelector('.form-control.line-total');

    //put the event hanldlers on
    selectControl.addEventListener("change", handleSelectChangeEvent);
    unitPrice.addEventListener("click", handlePriceBaseEvent);
    cloneRow.querySelector('.remove-row').addEventListener("click", handleTableRowRemoval);

    // add count where needed
    cloneRow.dataset.Count = newThings.count;
    cloneRow.id = `tablerow${newThings.count}`;

    selectControl.name = `Item_Id[${newThings.count}`;
    selectControl.textContent = newThings.count;
    selectControl.dataset.Id = newThings.count;

    measureBy.name = `MeasureBy[${newThings.count}`;
    measureBy.id = `MeasureBy[${newThings.count}`;

    qtyBase.name = `Qty[${newThings.count}`;
    qtyBase.id = `Qty[${newThings.count}`;
    qtyBase.dataset.QtyId = newThings.count;

    unitPrice.name = `Unit_Price[${newThings.count}`;
    unitPrice.id = `Unit_Price[${newThings.count}`;
    unitPrice.dataset.PriceId = newThings.count;

    lineTotal.name = `Line_Total[${newThings.count}`;
    lineTotal.id = `Line_Total[${newThings.count}`;
    lineTotal.dataset.PriceId = newThings.count;

    // Populate the <select> element with options
    newThings.dropdownOptions.forEach(function(option) {
      const optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      $(selectControl).append(optionElement);
    });

    // append new row to table after all that 
    table.appendChild(cloneRow);
    //only seems to work after append
    $(table).find(newThings.selectSelector).last().select2();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/* if for example using bootstrap can perhaps use classes from there instead */

.forty-percent {
  width: 40%;
}

.ten-percent {
  width: 10%;
}

.twenty-percent {
  width: 10%;
}

.count-items .label-count-value {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button id="add" type="button" class="add-new-row">Add new row</button>
<table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable" data-currentcount="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>MEASURE BY</th>
      <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
      <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0 ">
    <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<template id="new-row">
<tr id="tablerow" class="row-thing"> 
  <td><label class="count-items"><strong class="label-count-value"></strong></label></td>
  <td class="forty-percent"><select class="form-select js-dropdown item-id" required="required" ></select></td>
  <td class="ten-percent"><input type="text" class="form-control qty-base" value="1" data-qty-Id='' required="required" /></td>
  <td class="ten-percent"><input type="text" class="form-control measure-by" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td class="twenty-percent"><input type="text" class="form-control unit-price"  value="0.00" data-PriceId='xx' required="required" /></td>
  <td class="twenty-percent"><input type="text" class="form-control line-total"  value="0.00" required="required" /></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row">x</button></td>
</tr>
</template>
```